# I am getting null when trying to select video from Google Photos

Tags: android, google-photos

I am getting `null` when trying to select video from Google Photos.
It works if the video is also stored in your **external memory** but its not working,
if its only available on google photos. I tried many solutions but don't know how to accomplish this. Below is the class that i use to get the URI.

```
public class FilePath {
    private static final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    private static final long MiB = 1024 * 1024;
    private static final long KiB = 1024;

    public static String getPath(final Context context, String string) {
        return getPath(context, Uri.parse(string));
    }

    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static String getFileSize(File file) {

        if (!file.isFile()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected a file");
        }
        final double length = file.length();

        if (length > MiB) {
            return format.format(length / MiB) + " MB";
        }
        if (length > KiB) {
            return format.format(length / KiB) + " KB";
        }
        return format.format(length) + " B";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are facing issue while selecting video from external or from both internal and external

Comment: @Amjad, im facing issue when i try to select a video from google photo app.

Comment: @ZubairRehman have you got the solution about this because I am also facing same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have no permission to read the media from which Google Photo sends you a file I suppose. You have to use `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` to open as an InputStream and show in your activity a photo which Google Photo sends you. Your code is unacceptable. Try to search SO for this topic. It was discussed a lot of times.

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction()){
                uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                if (uri != null) {
                    InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    long fileSize = is.available()
                    //Do some suff to show stream as a picture in the Activity
                }
            }
```

This code works for me with last Google Photos app on Android 7.0 when picture is stored on the internal phone memory. **If Google Photos keeps a desired file somewhere on a cloud you have to load data from `is` in the background thread to avoid `Networking on main thread` exception.**

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @isabsent , i tried below mentioned code but getting `FileNotFoundException`:

    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

Comment: Where is the photo you are trying to view is placed PHYSICALLY?

Comment: The above code will work only when that picture is physically located on your phone or also on google photos. In my case the picture is not physically located on device, It is located only on google photos. 
`uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);` it returns null.

Comment: What do you mean under "located only on google photos"!? Google Photos keeps fies on your phone or on some cloud. I have a photo located on cloud and accessed by means Google Photos and I am able to read it by means of code above (in background thread). You have to set breakpoint in the place where you get `intent` and view what kind of sending you have in this `intent` i.e. `action`, `scheme`, `mime type`, `clip data` etc. Write all this info here, please.

Comment: Unfortunetely I can't reproduce your situation. It seems you are using old Google Photos app (2015). You will find a lot of workarounds for your case googling for `com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider` 
 - https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=Y0sQWpf2POOF6QSflrHwDw&q=android+how+to+view+photo+%22com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider%22&oq=android+how+to+view+photo+%22com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...125212.125679.0.126663.2.2.0.0.0.0.146.288.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.wiNvo460CB0

Comment: Google Photos 2017 sends a file from Google Drive cloud with an `intent` as on [this picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5imoihnm6ralyo/so_01.png?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks for your help bro :)

Comment: You are welcome! Try to install last Google Photos from Google Play and check how does it work with your file.